# How can I set what shows up for the link preview on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-opengraph

Everytime, I paste my client's homepage URL into Facebook, it pulls content from the blog, which doesn't actually stream on the homepage. What can I do to fix this bug?

The URL in question is http://StepitUpWithSteph.com.

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Liz

Answer (score 0):

inspect your url with [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://stepitupwithsteph.com/). Then update your OG meta tags. And the deubgger itself it's the only way to force refresh cached data by facebook.

Comment: Oh thank you for that tip --- I just put it in the debugger and it says... Object at URL 'http://stepitupwithsteph.com/healthy-alcoholic-beverages-how-to-feel-confident-around-your-crush/' of type 'article' is invalid because the domain 'stepitupwithsteph.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '356567741067890'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/356567741067890.

Comment: Actually - what's weirder is that it says the URL is http://stepitupwithsteph.com, but that the 'Canonical URL' is the URL of that blog post...

Comment: The simplest way is to create new fb app and add that domain, that's all. If you can't do that, remove og app id and use fb_admin and set it too some fb profile ID (administator)

Comment: Ohh! Okay-- I will give it a try and report back. :)

Comment: Okay so I set a new FB app for the domain and it isn't fixed yet - it said it takes several minutes.